# passing value from HTML to typescript while instantiating a component in angular 2

Tags: angular

I am deriving from a third party control to create my own custom component in angular 2 as follows :

```
     @Component({
        selector:"my-kendo-grid"
         inputs: [gridType2]
        })

      export class myClass implements OnInit{
         @Input gridType:string;
          gridType2 : string;

         ngOnInit(){
         console.log(this.gridType);
         console.log(this.gridType2);

      }
```

And than i am instantiating this component in another component(in parent component) as follows :

```
<my-kendo-grid [gridType]="'test'" [gridType2]="test2"></my-kendo-grid>
```

Now i want to pass a string value "test" from parent component and from html file itself not from .ts file. so that i can use it in the constructor or ngOnInit in my child component.

But when i am doing this, i am getting undefined in console in child component in both cases.

Comment: What is "html file itself"? Please add the code that shows what you're explaining.

Comment: Hi Gunter, "html file itself" means only from html file not from .ts file.

Comment: What HTML file? The `index.html` or a components template?

Comment: this is a components template which has code as below:                            <my-kendo-grid [gridType]="'test'" [gridType2]="test2"></my-kendo-grid>.                                                                                                      But i am getting 'undefined' in ngOnInit console. But when i made a button in child component, and on their click event i am getting the string value 'test' and 'test2'. But I want that value on ngOnInit, not on any click event

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: I have still troubles to understand what the problem is. Perhaps you wanted to added quotes here as well like `[gridType2]="'test2'"` (like you did with ` [gridType]="'test'"`)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using property binding `[gridType]` as you wanted to pass direct string value to component. In such case, directly use attribute and have value in that attribute. It will passed directly to component `binding`.

```
<my-kendo-grid gridType="test" gridType2="test2"></my-kendo-grid>
```

Comment: that got work? and do you wanted to pass string value in bindings, correct?

Comment: Hi Pankaj, i tried what you said :                                                            <my-kendo-grid gridType="test" gridtype2="test2"></my-kendo-grid> .    But i am getting 'undefined' in ngOnInit console. But when i made a button in child component, and on their click event i am getting the string value 'test' and 'test2'. But I want that value on ngOnInit, not on any click event.